# Can we force a function call to complete and return before proceeding to next statement in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, synchronous

Here I have a simple HTTP server. When `foo()` is called, it fetches a value based on key. But it turns out, when `foo(key, redisClient)` is called, it prints

> I am inside foo

And then immediately goes on to report

```
x is null
```

By this time the asynchronous redis.get call is over, and now I see

> About to return from foo with result: 1

which is the value I was expecting. But by now my error check is over and it has already written error in the HTTP response. How do I ensure that I actually get a proper return value from `foo()` to store into `x` before I proceed with anything else in the main server thread?

```
var http = require('http');
var redis = require("redis");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var x = null;
    var key = "key";
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    x = foo(key, redisClient);

    if(x == null)
    {
        // report error and quit
                console.log('x is null');
                // write error message and status in HTTP response
    }
    // proceed
        console.log('Proceeding...');
        // do some stuff using the value returned by foo to var x
        // .........
        // .........
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1400, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1400/');


function foo(key, redisClient)
{
    console.log('I am inside foo');
    redisClient.get(key, function(error, result) {
        if(error) console.log('error:' + error);
        else
            {
                    console.log('About to return from foo with result:' + result);
                    return result;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return in redisClient.get()'s call won't pass on to foo()'s return.  You need to pass the value back in the callback.  Here is the revise code:

```
var http = require('http');
var redis = require("redis");
var me = this;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var x = null;
    var key = "key";
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    me.foo(key, redisClient, function(err, result) {
       x = result;
       if(x == null)
       {
       // report error and quit
               console.log('x is null');
               // write error message and status in HTTP response
       }
       // proceed
        console.log('Proceeding...');
        // do some stuff using the value returned by foo to var x
        // .........
       // .........
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
       res.end('Hello World\n');
    });

}).listen(1400, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1400/');


function foo(key, redisClient, callback)
{
  console.log('I am inside foo');
  redisClient.get(key, function(error, result) {
    if(error)  {
        console.log('error:' + error);
        callback (error);
    } else {
        console.log('About to return from foo with result:' + result);
        callback(null, result);
    }
  }
}
```